# Maths book recommendation for engineering

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I am an engineering student and I need a book that will give me a thorough understanding of concepts and also its applications for calculus.
Can you recommend two separate books one for concepts and other for applications?
I heard Tom Apostol is good ,are there any good options?

Answer (score 1):

Calculus: Early Transcendentals by James Stewart will give you a thorough introduction to single and multi-variate calculus.

Another very similar book is Calculus: Early Transcendentals by Anton, Bivens, and Davis. They are very similar and not much separates them.

These two have plenty of problem sets applicable to a very wide range of fields.

Also highly recommended is Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering by Riley, Hobson, and Bence is another good general reference book, but not really an introductory text.